# VBA Application.Run syntax

Tags: vba

I have an add-in that I would like to call from another workbook. The add-in is called "status" and is placed in the folder "Test". The Sub in the add-in is called Workbook_AfterSave.

The Sub I want to call is initiated like this:

```
Public Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
```

What would the right syntax be to call that specific Sub? I would think:

```
Application.Run "Test\status.xlam!Workbook_AfterSave"
```

But that doesn't work. I get the error message : "The macro may not be available is this workbook or all macros may be disabled."

The path above is simplyfied, I did enter the full path to the Sub.

Any suggestions?

Kind regards 
Erik

Comment: Remove the path. You also need to pass the `Success` parameter.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the succes parameter and yes, it does work without the path, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.Run "'C:\Test\status.xlam'!ThisWorkbook.Workbook_AfterSave", True
```

(supposing the path you provided is on volume `C:`)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot! :)